# Is there a limit on how much rep I can give away?

Tags: support

Now that I've reached 25K, I'm not really interested in the next level: 100K is too far off and too much trouble for a T-shirt and a mug...

So I've been giving away all my rep above 25K (sort of) to:

- Original answers
- Interesting answers
- Answers that helped me in the past
- Answers that took a lot of work, but got few upvotes.
- ...

The question is:

*Will I trigger any limit that will take away any of my rep without my explicit consent if I keep doing this for the next couple of years?*

Comment: Hi Fabby, you're incredible, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! (And deserve it) @JacobVlijm

Comment: Thank you. Your thoughtfulness is noticed and appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do this all the time, mostly to help out people who might have been buried in the noise.

You can only do three bounties at a time, and due to the time restrictions it makes it tough to do bulk bounties. The "interest" from my old answers ends up making up for it.

I find that it can be just as challenging to find good questions to bounty as it is to answer them; it's a pretty fun way to help people out, good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Nope. [Just ask Jorge Castro](https://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro?tab=bounties&sort=offered).